# How can I avoid electrostatic discharge?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, everyday-life

I recently started an internship in an office with a rugged floor everywhere.

After a few days, I started receiving electrostatic discharge all the time after I walked a little bit around the floor (probably due to the rug).

Everytime I walk around, and then come back to my computer, I get shocked when I touch it.

Things I tried:

- Using different shoes to prevent the electrostatic buildup
- Change my power adapter, so it would be better grounded (don't know if it actually makes sense, but I tried anyway)
- Changing various devices at my desk (monitor, smartphone charger, etc.)

Things I cannot do (I'm not alone in this office)

- Removing the rug (obviously)
- Wear an electrostatic wrist strap (unless they exist without having to be clamped somewhere)
- Setting the humidity level in the office

Is there any trick I could use to avoid getting shocked after I walked on the rug?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4180/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18073/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Woops, I thought I had searched it on this site before, but it looks like I mixed my research

Comment: Just search around the web for products with the ESD logo on it. There are pads for your desktop or shoes which should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the suggestions on page 3 of this [brochure](https://intranet.birmingham.ac.uk/hr/documents/public/hsu/information/electrical/staticelectricity.pdf) can help?

Can you walk around the office in socks? Maybe you can ask your employer for one of those static dissipative floor treatments that the document mentions?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot walk around in socks, as an intern that would look unprofessional (maybe I'd ask the question on "The Workplace" ..). Also the dissipative treatment seems much. I'll take a look at the links @Qmechanic gave. Thanks though :)

Comment: Indeed. Good luck solving the issue then!