# Can the human body utilize electricity?

Tags: energy, electrostatics, biophysics, ionization-energy

Can the molecules human body be positively charged by electrons and not discharged?

Can the body atoms be ionized?

When you body get a jolt of energy other than muscle tension and adrenaline why are you left feeling energized?

Example asked by commentator: When you rub your feet on carpet you pick up electrons. Times that by 100 and if you don't discharge and not touch anything can it be processed by your body?

[image]

Comment: Sure, molecules in the human body can become positively charged, if they lose an electron, just like any other molecule. I have no idea what you mean by "process the electrons through exercise if retained and not discharged". Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: perhaps relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_capacitance

Comment: @Brionius updated question

Comment: What does the picture add to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your body doesn't "process" the excess charge - it simply leaks away to the environment. In winter, when the humidity is low, that process is quite slow; this is why you can get "zapped" after getting charged up by walking across the carpet, then touching a metal door knob for example.

I wrote an answer about the mechanisms of discharge a while ago - see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/130988/26969)

Note - because conservation of charge is a fundamental law of physics, a body in isolation cannot make charge "disappear". Either ions of opposite charge have to be added, or ions with the same charge have to disappear. There is no equivalent to white blood cells "eating" bacteria when it comes to electrical charge.